# Formularios en Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una situación con un formulario en mi proyecto de web, y mi formulario varia de inputs de acuerdo con cantidad de datos en la BD.

Esto quiere decir que al yo tomar información de los N inputs debo hacer N inserciones a otra tabla, por lo cual requiero que mi objeto que llega a mi controlador sea una lista y no un objeto, pero no se como debo hacer para que el formulario envíe una lista a mi controlador.

Uso atributos asp `action` para la comunicación entre vista y controlador, gracias

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código para que puedan ofrecerte más ayuda

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta, e indica el código que has hecho. Indica el/los Modelos, la Vista y el Controlador.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.